# CSS - Placing image next to centered text

Tags: html, css, position

I'm pretty well versed with HTML and CSS, but I'd like your opinion on this one!

[image: menu]

I need to center the text in the arrow, but place a check box next to the centered text. Because of this, I can't user `text-align` on all of the contents of the arrow, like I normally would. If I include the check in the centering, the anchor point shifts off of the text to include the check, and the text isn't truly centered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the check an absolutely positioned span, set as display:block, positioned relative to the text. Check out this jsFiddle for a basic idea. Your HTML may be set up differently:

- http://jsfiddle.net/cGG3W/1/

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, you could

1. use `text-align:center;` on the text in the `div`.
2. place the checkmark in another `div` and position it where necessary.  You may need to adjust the stack.